# XSSI protection by adding prefix to JSON response

Tags: rest, security, xss

Angular's security guide mentions prefixing JSON responses from APIs to protect against XSSI:

> This attack is only successful if the returned JSON is executable as JavaScript. Servers can prevent an attack by prefixing all JSON responses to make them non-executable, by convention, using the well-known string ")]}',\n".

The part I don't understand is, when you add such a prefix to a JSON response, it stops being a valid JSON. Isn't it an issue?

Comment: `if the returned JSON is executable as JavaScript` meaning you don't escape html characters in the response, mainly `<script>` and use the response directly in your html. In your case just `<` -> ` &lt;`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it stops being a valid JSON. But Angular strips the string before parsing as JSON so it doesn't break anything, if you use it with Angular.

> Angular's HttpClient library recognizes this convention and automatically strips the string ")]}',\n" from all responses before further parsing.